# How to solve $x^x = y^y \mod p$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, tetration

Let $p>5$ be a prime.

How to solve $x^x = y^y \mod p$?
How many solutions are there for a given $p$ such that $x,y < p$?

I know the discrete logarithm and the theory of quadratic residues, but I'm not sure if that helps.

---

Question 2

How many $p$ exist such that at least $(p-1)/2$ residues are of the form

$$ r = a^b = b^a \mod p $$

Comment: could write some code, print out a sequence and check oeis

Comment: $ (x) log_y(x) = y $ (mod p)  by discrete log change of base formula and the trivial identity for the discrete logarithm, namely that it's inverse is exponentiation. So solving the general case reduces to solving this formula

Comment: @NaN did it, the sequence is not in OEIS. I could not find any pattern. I allowed $x=0$ and $y=0$ and assumed $0^0=1$. It is still possible that omitting the $x=0-y=0$ cases leads to a sequence. I will also check this.

Comment: No, without the cases $x=0$ and $y=0$ the result is also negative.

Comment: Shall I give the values as an answer ? If yes, with or without the cases $x=0$ and $y=0$ ?

Comment: Maybe someone can program and check question $2$ ...

Comment: give the values somewhere on the internet or conveniently as an answer

Comment: Solutions to your equation are not well defined mod $p$: if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $(x+mp,y+np)$ need not be a solution, and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 1):

question 1: $x\equiv y$ is the trivial answer. knowing parity arguments seems more useful, odd mod odd is opposite the integer multiplier for example. So $3^3$ is 6 mod 7 so it's multiplier is odd (3 in fact). $3^5$ is 5 mod 7 so it's multiplier is even (34 which is 6 mod 7 in this case). So odd pairs (x,y) depend on being in the same parity multiplier. You can do similar mod 3 etc. That will narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- It seems that there is no efficient algorithm to calculate solutions and it is almost certain that there is no direct formula for this. In general we can assure that $1^1=(p-1)^{p-1}=1$  but it seems that there are several solutions in many cases for example for $p = 11$ we have $9^9=8^8=3^3=6^6=5$